# Layers Question

Tags: carto, layers

I'm currently mapping with a free account on CartoDB but I've run into a roadblock. I need to add multiple visualization layers onto my map but the free account limits me to merely four. Is there any way around this while continuing to use a free account, or would an upgrade fix this problem?

Comment: mapping with what service?

Comment: I'm currently mapping with CartoDB

Comment: The [CartoDB pricing page](http://cartodb.com/pricing-features) doesn't seem to list a limitation of 4 layers, so it's possible that there is something else amiss. What makes you say that you're limited to 4 layers?

Comment: Welcome to gis.se. Please edit your thread title to a meaningful question which provides enough details for future readers who might come here with a similar problem looking for solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You can have up to 6 layers in the **Editor**, depending on your CartoDB account. You can check the info in this [link](http://docs.cartodb.com/faqs.html#how-many-layers-can-my-visualization-have).

Even so, if you use [CartoDB.js](https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb.js/) you can have "unlimited" layers. You can check a course about it this [link](http://academy.cartodb.com/courses/03-cartodbjs-ground-up.html).